# Load properties file in jmeter then assign properties value to JMeter variable

Tags: jmeter

I have condition where I need to load properties file and assign prop value to JMeter UDV.

I have been able to load property file successful, however I can not assign prop value to UDV

I have try the following:

1. Load prop file contain key value (i.e `var_from_prop_file=1000`)
2. Create UDV (with keyname "`my.var`" and value "`${var_from_prop_file}`")

Run debug script with debug sampler, I can see `var_from_prop_file` assigned to value `1000`

However my.var still empty (no value). 
my expectation when creating UDV with `my.var = ${var_from_prop_file}`, `my.var` value will be `1000` too, but it doesn't happen here.

I have try with `__eval` and _`_evalVar` - no luck so far.

Is it possible to reference jmeter variable to properties file key?
and call variable in other place?

So far from debug sampler - looks like jmeter load UDV first and then jmeter properties not the way around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your tries are getting variables , you need to get property using different [functions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

In your case set `my.var` with the following value

```
${__P(var_from_prop_file)}
```

Or

```
${__property(var_from_prop_file)}
```

Similar result, just notice that `__P` have default value 1

> The default value for the property. If omitted, the default is set to "1".

Another option is using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) using `vars` to set variable and `props` to get property:

```
vars.put("my.var", props.get("var_from_prop_file"));
```

Comment: The first `${__P(var_from_prop_file)}` doesn't work for me, but the second one works perfectly, when i set in UDV `my.var = ${__property(var_from_prop_file)}`, i can see in debug sampler `my.var = 100` and `var_from_prop_file=100` too. Kinda weird, according to jmeter manual both `__P` and `__property` read the same thing

Answer (score 5):

The fastest way to bulk convert JMeter Properties into JMeter Variables is using [JSR223 Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) and the following code:

```
SampleResult.setIgnore()

props.entrySet().each {entry ->
    vars.putObject(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue())
}
```

Where:

- `SampleResult.setIgnore()` - removes JSR223 Sampler from listeners and .jtl results file
- `props` - shorthand for JMeter Properties (basically an instance of [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html))
- `vars` - shorthand for the instance of [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class